# Just installed Ubuntu 23.04 and trouble with Intel AX200 Wifi kernel driver

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I installed Ubuntu 23.04, on the previous version of Ubuntu the wifi worked no problem, this version 23.04, the wifi does not work.

`lspci` shows the wifi device is there but it is not working, I do not know how to enable the wifi at command line,

Is there any fix for this?

`sudo modprob  iwlwifi` returned nothing.

`sudo dmesg | grep iwl` returned

```
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with fatal error -110
```

and

```
iwlwifi 000:05:00.0: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
```

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: no its not dual boot

Comment: Please stop editing my post, if I wanted to be more formal I can do it myself. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I disabled the Secure Boot and it works now. To disable the secure boot, run $sudo mokutil --disable-validation$ in a terminal and reboot. At bios start, press a key for MDK management. Enter the character required from your password and you can disable the Secure Boot.
Wifi should work then.
For example, for my laptop:

```
sudo lshw -C network
$*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:93:00.0
   logical name: wlp147s0
   version: 1a
   serial: 8c:1d:96:93:0e:e5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.14.0-1034-oem firmware=73.35c0a2c6.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-73.uc ip=192.168.1.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
   resources: irq:17 memory:b5200000-b5203fff
```